# Inserting images into a column from another column via formula function in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to show image in a column from another column which contains URL sources.
With struggle I write following code as a custom user **formula** function, but:

- **It is always jumping to "Err" block**
- **It is inserting images, but inserting into the current selected cell that on Excel interface, not the cell that Excel rendering. So XPos and YPos below never using by Excel...**

How to solve these? Thank you!

```
Public Function ShowImage(PicFile As String)
    XPos = ActiveSheet.Range(Application.Caller.Address).Cells(0, 0).Left
    YPos = ActiveSheet.Range(Application.Caller.Address).Cells(0, 0).Top
    On Error GoTo Err
        With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PicFile)
            With .ShapeRange
                .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                .Width = 75
                .Height = 100
            End With
            .LinkToFile = msoFalse
            .SaveWithDocument = msoFalse
            .Left = XPos
            .Top = YPos
            .PrintObject = True
        End With
Done:
    ShowImage = "Done"
    Exit Function
Err:
    ShowImage = "Error"
End Function
```

Comment: Please specify what the error is in your questions.

Comment: There is not error message thrown, neigher on log screen, nor alert message. Script is only jumping to "Err" block.

Comment: Ok. Why are those positions defined with "ActiveSheet.Range(Application.Caller.Address).Cells(0, 0).Left"?

Comment: Step through the code. Where does it jump to Err? Remove the `On Error` or use the `Err:` properly to get the error code. That's basic troubleshooting.

Comment: Because it is giving the current rendering formula cell positions, maybe it should be the longest way to get positions, I know... I tested and get the left and top values correctly, but somehow ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert.Left ignores the definitions.